# How to animate width of a button in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-button, android-compose-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

Let's say I have a Composable like this :

```
@Composable
fun LoadingButton() {
    val (isLoading, setIsLoading) = state { false }

    Button(
        onClick = setIsLoading,
        text = {
            if (isLoading) {
                Text(text = "Short text")
            } else {
                Text(text = "Very very very long text")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

How can I animate the width update of my button ?

I'm well aware that I could add a preferredWidth modifier to the button and animate this width with :

```
val buttonWidth = animate(target = if (isLoading) LoadingButtonMinWidth else LoadingButtonMaxWidth)
```

But this is not my what I want. I need to animate the automatic "wrap-content" width.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to add an `animateContentSize` modifier to the `Text` Composable:

```
@Composable
fun LoadingButton() {
    val (isLoading, setIsLoading) = state { false }
    Button(onClick = { setIsLoading(!isLoading) }) {
        Text(
            text = if (isLoading) {
               "Short text"
            } else {
                "Very very very long text"
            },
            modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize()
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can apply the modifier [**`animateContentSize`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/package-summary#animatecontentsize)

This modifier animates its own size when its child modifier (or the child composable if it is already at the tail of the chain) changes size. This allows the parent modifier to observe a smooth size change, resulting in an overall continuous visual change.

Something like:

```
var isLoading by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val text = if (isLoading) "Short text" else "Very very very long text"

Button(onClick = { isLoading = !isLoading },
    modifier = Modifier
        .animateContentSize(
              animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300,
                   easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing))
) {
    Text(
        text = text,textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
```

[image]